# How to remove extra blank line after one entry of bibliography (I am using apacite)

Tags: spacing, bibliographies, apa-style, apa6

I am using `apacite` and BibTeX to create my bibliography / reference section.  However, after one of the entries, there is an extra blank line.  If I remove one character that is on the last line of the entry above the blank line, the line goes away, but I need to keep all characters.  Also, this isn't the first time I have had this happen to me, so I would like to find a way to solve it automatically (programmatically).

Here is what I am doing:

```
\documentclass[12pt, man]{apa6}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{placeins}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{dcolumn}
\usepackage [english]{babel}
\usepackage [autostyle, english = american]{csquotes}
\MakeOuterQuote{"}
\usepackage{apacite}

\author{NS}
\title{Title}
\shorttitle{Short Title}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\section{Introduction}
This is a sentence \cite{Steif2004}.  This is another \cite{AtesCataloglu2007}. And one more \cite{Dewey1997}. Website \cite{GravityLightn.d.}.  Book section \cite{Lave1991}. Electronic book \cite{Learningn.d.}.
\medskip

\bibliographystyle{apacite} 
\bibliography{test5.bib}

\end{document}
```

And here are the relevent portions of my .bib file.

```
@Article{AtesCataloglu2007,
  author =  {Ates, Salih and Cataloglu, Erdat},
  title =   {The effects of students' cognitive styles on conceptual understandings and problem-solving skills in introductory mechanics},
  journal = {Research in Science \& Technological Education},
  year =    {2007},
  volume =  {25},
  number =  {2},
  pages =   {167-178},
  doi =     {10.1080/02635140701250618}
}

@Misc{Steif2004,
  author =       {Steif, Paul S.},
  title =        {Initial data from a statics concept inventory},
  howpublished = {Paper presented at ASEE Annual Conference and Exposition},
  year =         {2004},
  address =      {Salt Lake City, UT},
  url =          {https://peer.asee.org/13849}
}

@Book{Dewey1997,
  title =     {Experience and education},
  publisher = {Touchstone},
  year =      {1997},
  author =    {Dewey, John},
  address =   {New York, NY}
}
```

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One possibility is to add `\usepackage{microtype}` to your preamble (see following MWE).  Another possibility is to print the bibliography only left justified with command `\raggedright` or better `\RaggedRight` (needs package `ragged2e` to be loaded).

MWE:

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@Article{AtesCataloglu2007,
  author =  {Ates, Salih and Cataloglu, Erdat},
  title =   {The effects of students' cognitive styles on conceptual 
             understandings and problem-solving skills in introductory 
             mechanics},
  journal = {Research in Science \& Technological Education},
  year    = {2007},
  volume =  {25},
  number =  {2},
  pages =   {167--178},
  doi     = {10.1080/02635140701250618},
}

@Misc{Steif2004,
  author =       {Steif, Paul S.},
  title =        {Initial data from a statics concept inventory},
  howpublished = {Paper presented at ASEE Annual Conference and Exposition},
  year =         {2004},
  address =      {Salt Lake City, UT},
  url =          {https://peer.asee.org/13849},
}

@Book{Dewey1997,
  title =     {Experience and education},
  publisher = {Touchstone},
  year =      {1997},
  author =    {Dewey, John},
  address =   {New York, NY},
}
\end{filecontents*}


\documentclass[12pt, man]{apa6}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[%
  autostyle, 
  english = american
]{csquotes}
\MakeOuterQuote{"}

\usepackage{microtype} % <==============================================

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{placeins}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{dcolumn}

\usepackage{apacite}
\usepackage{showframe}

\author{NS}
\title{Title}
\shorttitle{Short Title}


\begin{document}

\maketitle

\section{Introduction}
This is a sentence \cite{Steif2004}.  
This is another \cite{AtesCataloglu2007}. 
And one more \cite{Dewey1997}. 
Website %\cite{GravityLightn.d.}.  Book section \cite{Lave1991}. Electronic book \cite{Learningn.d.}.
\medskip

\bibliographystyle{apacite} 
\bibliography{\jobname} % test5.bib

\end{document}
```

and the result:

[image]

With `\RaggedRight` add

```
\usepackage{ragged2e}
```

to your preamble and use

```
{\RaggedRight
\bibliographystyle{apacite} 
\bibliography{\jobname} % test5.bib
}
```

to print only the bibliography left justified.

Comment: I added the add \usepackage{microtype} and it worked perfectly!  What a simple solution; thank you!

Comment: I had the same issue. The 'microtype' package did nothing for me. The RaggedRight solved it. Thank you!

Comment: @TobiasHotzenplotz i think you need to run with pdflatex, not xelatex to get this